# How to get the post_id from postmeta

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch the `post_id` from the `wp_postmeta` table, here is the code I'm using:

```php
if(isset($_POST['patientid'])) { //user enters the patientid

    $thevalue = $_POST['patientid'];
    $tbl = $wpdb->prefix.'postmeta';

    $prepare_guery = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM $tbl WHERE meta_key ='patientid' AND meta_value LIKE $thevalue", $meta_value );

    $get_values = $wpdb->get_col( $prepare_guery );
    echo $get_values;
}
```

but this only prints out "Array", that's it.

Can anyone please tell me what I should change? Thank you!

Comment: `$get_values` isn't returned as a string by `$wpdb`, which is why you're seeing the string "Array" being echo'd. Try changing `echo $get_values;` to `$get_values[0]->post_id`.

Answer (score 1):

There's the WordPress meta API for retrieving meta values from the `wp_postmeta` table, but the API doesn't provide a function for retrieving the post ID (`post_id` value), but you can use custom SQL as in your code.

However, [`$wpdb->get_col()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_col/) returns an array of values (upon success), so that's why you get the "Array" when you do `echo $get_values;`.

So you can either do something like this:

```php
$post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $prepare_guery ); // returns an array of IDs on success
$post_id = $post_ids[0]; // simplified - assuming that $post_ids[0] is actually set
var_dump( $post_ids ); // for testing
```

Or (a simpler option) if you want to retrieve just a single value, you should use [`$wpdb->get_var()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_var/):

```php
$post_id = $wpdb->get_var( $prepare_guery ); // returns a string (an ID) on success
```

### Additional Notes

```php
$prepare_guery = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM $tbl WHERE meta_key ='patientid' AND meta_value LIKE $thevalue", $meta_value );
```

should be:

```php
$prepare_guery = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM $tbl WHERE meta_key ='patientid' AND meta_value LIKE %s", $wpdb->esc_like( $thevalue ) );
```

I.e. Note the `%s` (placeholder) and I also use `$wpdb->esc_like()`. I also realized that the `$meta_value` is not defined in your code, hence I changed that (in the above code) to `$thevalue`.

And in the previous revisions, I misspelled the `$prepare_guery` as `$prepare_query`... or did you mean `$prepare_query` ?